# How to reproduce my Finder tags as OpenMeta tags

Tags: finder-tag, macos

I am using a suite of applications to manage files, somewhat like a distributed digital assets manager. I tag my files using Finder tags with several apps--Finder, HoudaSpot, Default Folder X, Leap--as is convenient at the time. However, some programs, notably Pixa, use OpenMeta tags to build its internal library. Therefore, if I use Pixa to browse folders where I organize images, I can't use my tagging scheme unless I painstakingly reproduce it using Pixa's tagging interface.

I've scoured the Internet for ways to simply copy Finder tags as OpenMeta tags but haven't found a way. HoudaSpot 3.8 had a feature under "Results" to merge the two, which I could make work, but that disappeared in 4.0.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, as this seems to be a workflow problem others would hit. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Update: I found someone online with a [script to do this](http://code2k.net/blog/2013-10-23/). But haven't tried it out yet. Anyone with scripting experience might check it out for potential problems.

Comment: I use [Leap](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/leap/) v3.6.2, and I have noticed that Leap adds OpenMeta tags to all files that are already tagged with Mavericks tags (if the files are not read-only) in any folder that I browse in Leap (so files that previously only had Mavericks tags now have OpenMeta tags too). So if you browse all files (deep) in Leap, it should add missing OpenMeta tags to all relevant files.